# How do I filter a list of urls by 200 response?

Tags: node.js

Basically, I have a list of 30 urls, and I want to do a `request({ method: 'head', url: url }).then(function(data){});`

The problem I'm having is that the `request-promise` is difficult to deal with because a 404 would trigger a `.catch` not a `.then`.

I basically just need to make sure these urls have a 200 response and if not remove them from the list.

I've tried with basic `async` and `request` (callback interface) but can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Just assume I have an array of urls to check and I want the function to return me that list filtered by 200 responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use async.filterSeries to filter out urls

```
async.filterSeries(
  ['url1','url2','url3'],
  function(url, callback) {
    request({ method: 'head', url: url })
    .then(function(data){
      callback(true);
    })
    .catch(function(){
      callback(false);
    });
  },
  function(results){

  }
);
```

filterSeries is used instead of filter, since the number of concurrent requests you can make to external host is limited in node, though you can increase the number. If you are hitting different hosts, you can use filter

Comment: Is that all?  Damn that's way easier than what I had in mind.

Comment: What's the difference? `filter` seemed to work fine. edit: what is the limit?

Comment: @chovy the thing is that the number of concurrent requests to a single host is limited set to 5 by default, which you can increase http.globalAgent.maxSockets, but if your urls are targeting different hosts you can use just filter